# how to fix the 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library'

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

I am trying to store location of stores in my django database, i tried installing geodjango for the purpose which gives me the above error.

i have installed 
python 
postgresql
osgeow
psycopg2
also modified the envirenment variables as per geodjango documentation

i tried installing gdal manually using -http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7.zip 
the generic core components

my settings.py file-

```py
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.gis',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'services',
        'USER': '*******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'PORT': '5434',
    }
```

when i run

```
python manage.py check
```

it gives me the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

i have already set the gdal ibrary path to gdal data directory, it still isn't working.

Please help with whatever's wrong above.

Also suggest if there is any other way to store locations in django database?

Comment: Try this `apt-get -y install python-gdal python-geoip rpl`

Comment: @ YugandharChaudhari - this throws a command not found error.

Comment: Which command not found

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari- this throws command not found error at apt-get.

Comment: Which OS you are using

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari - I am using windoelws 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simply switched to linux and it worked.Although the problem was somewhere there was a library that windows couldn't figure out,switching to linux solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `gdal300` too on the GDAL library. When you install GDAL as of now, you get 
`gdal300` in `OSGeo4w64/bin` directory.
 Next, you might get an error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: jsonfield dependency missing`

There is an easy fix for it. `pip install jsonfield`

This should work.
If this didn't work

run this as a bat script in your command prompt.

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python3X
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_ROOT%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session 
Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session 
Manager\Environment" /v GDAL_DATA /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%GDAL_DATA%"
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session 
Manager\Environment" /v PROJ_LIB /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PROJ_LIB%"
```

Note: you need to rename `c:/OSGEO4w64' to`c:/OSGEO4w` in your c drive to work with the script shown above.

Find detail here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/

Answer (score 0):

I ran this and it worked for me.

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python3X
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
```